# Why does the memory address change after slice assignment

Tags: go

There are two problems I don't understand. 
The first one is that one slice variable is assigned to another variable, and it is found that the address of the new variable is inconsistent with that of the variable. My understanding is that slice shares memory, and their addresses are the same according to the principle.

the Second is then when the slice variable is insufficient in capacity, the memory address does not change after the append operation. It should change according to the principle, because the memory address will be newly allocated when the capacity is insufficient.

I would appreciate your comments.

```
var a = []int{1,2,3}
fmt.Printf("%p\n",&a)
b:=a
fmt.Printf("%p\n",&b) 1)、the first question
b=append(b,0)
fmt.Printf("%p\n",&b) 2)、the second question
fmt.Println(a)
fmt.Println(b)
```

run result is:

```
0xc04204c3a0
0xc04204c3e0
0xc04204c3e0
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3 0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slice value contains a pointer to the backing array, length and capacity.  See [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) for the details.

Here's some commentary on the code in the question:

```
var a = []int{1, 2, 3}

// Print address of variable a
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &a)

b := a

// Print address of variable b. The variable a and b
// have different addresses.
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &b)

b = append(b, 0)

// Print address of variable b. Append did not change
// the address of the variable b.
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &b)
```

Print the address of the first slice element to get the results you expect.

```
var a = []int{1, 2, 3}

// Print address of a's first element
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &a[0])

b := a

// Print address of b's first element. This prints
// same value as previous because a and b share a backing
// array.
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &b[0])

b = append(b, 0)

// Print address of b's first element. This prints a 
// different value from previous because append allocated
// a new backing array.
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &b[0])
```

Comment: thank you,I mistakenly think that the structure variable stores the entire data.

Answer (score 1):

```
// create a new slice struct which contains length, capacity and the underlying array. 
// len(a)=3, cap(a)=3
var a = []int{1,2,3}

// `&a` means the pointer to slice struct
fmt.Printf("%p\n",&a)

// `b` is another newly created variable of slice struct, so `&b` differs from `&a`, 
// but they share the same underlying array.
// len(b)=3, cap(b)=3
b := a

// the underlying array of `b` has been extended, and been newly allocated.
// but the pointer of `b` remains.
// len(b)=4, cap(b)=6
b = append(b, 0)
```

Hope that these comments can help you